# Dynamic tab Closed When I refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic tabs.

I need when I refresh the page that tabs should not be closed

Script:

```js
var button = '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button>';
var tabID = 1;

function resetTab() {
  var tabs = $("#tab-list li:not(:first)");
  var len = 1
  $(tabs).each(function(k, v) {
    len++;
    $(this).find('a').html('Tab ' + len + button);
  })
  tabID--;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
    tabID++;
    $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + tabID + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button></a></li>'));
    $('#tab-content').append($('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab' + tabID + '">Tab ' + tabID + ' content</div>'));
  });
  $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function() {
    var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
    $(this).parents('li').remove();
    $(tabID).remove();

    //display first tab
    var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
    resetTab();
    tabFirst.tab('show');
  });

  var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>
      <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Tab</button>
    </p>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">Tab 1 content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you need to store something in localStorage or sessionStorage and read it when you load the page

Comment: When you refresh a page all the code (html, js and css) is re-sended and re.executed. Everything was in your page is destroyed. You can handle persistence with cookies and use it to "save" the state of your page once you get out. localStorage is good for that as well

Comment: Also you can remove `var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");`

Answer (score -1):

all you could do is to tell the users to not leave the page.
there is no way to prevent closing due to security and anti spam reasons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

using `window.onbeforeunload` will at least give you the opportunity to do some cleanup during that function call like writing data to local or session storage or throwing a syncronous request to your api and return a message to the user so he can decide if he would like to unload the current window by navigating away or not.
the example above set's the text in two different ways due to cross browser issues.
you can read more about that in the corresponding MDN article linked above.